# Как определить реальные координаты x и y, ширину и высоту у DIV, даже если они не заданы стилями

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как определить реальные координаты x и y, ширину и высоту у элемента DIV, даже если они не заданы стилями?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, там что-то про ширину и высоту сказано?)

Comment: Там в ответе сказано про `getBoundingClientRect()`, который возвращает также и ширину с высотой.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, но речь о ширине и высоте там не идёт

Comment: Вызов `console.log( element.getBoundingClientRect() )` вернёт всё, что нужно. + может понадобится значение `element.scrollTop`. Когда я это дописал, то понял, что фактически повторил свой ответ в том вопросе, потому и считаю этот вопрос дубликатом. У тебя же 10к, мой удаленный ответ должен видеть.

Comment: Добавил в свой оригинальный ответ, что вызов возвращает еще и ширину с высотой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Координаты, ширину и высоту можно узнавать через функцию `getBoundingClientRect()`. Ещё ширину и высоту можно узнавать через функции `offsetWidth` и `offsetHeight`. Эти две функции выводят округлённые размеры, в то время, как `getBoundingClientRect()` выводит число с дробью.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.element');

var width = element.offsetWidth || element.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    height = element.offsetHeight || element.getBoundingClientRect().height,
    position = {
      left: element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      top: element.getBoundingClientRect().top,
      right: element.getBoundingClientRect().right,
      bottom: element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
    };

console.log(
  'Width: '+width+';\nHeight: '+height+';\nPosition Top: '+position.top+';\nPosition: Left: '+position.left+';\nPosition Right: '+position.right+';\nPosition Bottom: '+position.bottom
);
```

```html
<span class="element">Текст</span>
```